# Imagefield in Django HTML Variable

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and trying to create a website with uploading image via Django Admin.

I'm trying to view image uploaded in Imagefield in my HTML.
But i just can't get the image working right.

Banner.objects.all() doesn't seems able to get all the image file located in media folder.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) #auto_now=True //auto date
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Banner(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import(
    ListView,
    DetailView
)

from .models import *

# Create your views here.
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted'] #arrange date posted with latest on top
    paginate_by = 6

def Banner_view(request):
    banner = Banner.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html',{'banner':banner})
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

#uploaded file in base directory "media"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

home.html

```
  {% for b in banner %}
  <div>
    <img src="{{ b.images.url }}">
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have write this way
you should use `/` for path detect

```
images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True,blank=True)
```